# Proving a group with two generators is not free that uses the Brahamagupta-Pell equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

Hello I encountered the following while reading a set of notes on free groups.  It's not a homework question.

"Does there exist a rational number $\alpha$ with $0 <|\alpha| < 2$ such that the group generated by $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \alpha \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ \alpha &1 \end{bmatrix}$ is free.

We mention in passing that several rational $\alpha$ with $0 < |\alpha| < 2$ are known for which the group generated by $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \alpha \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ \alpha &1 \end{bmatrix}$ is NOT free.  The proof interestingly goes via the Brahmagupta-Pell equation."

I was unable to find references that explain this problem  and attempted proofs that go through the Brahmagupta-Pell equation.  Where may I be able to find some exposition of this?  I did contact the author but have not received not yet received a response.  If I do, I'll post it.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

*** EDIT ***
Thank you for your comments.  Dr. Sapir provided me with information that led me to using additional search criteria.  The reference that I found that helps answer the question is in a paper by A.F. Beardon:

"Pell's Equation and two generator free Mobius groups" that is found in the Bull. London Math Soc. 25 (1993) 527-532.

Dr. Beardon considers irrational values of $\alpha$.  Obviously, I haven't fully read the paper yet but it does provide another reference to a paper by Lyndon and Ullman

"Groups generated by two linear parabolic transformations", Canadian Journal of Math 21 (1969) 1388-1403

that provides insight on when this group can be free for a given rational value of $\alpha$.

So, thank you again! I greatly appreciated the assistance!  Now I have more enjoyable (and productive) reading to do!

Comment: I don't know what this problem was intending, but, writing $e(\alpha) = \begin{bmatrix} 1&\alpha \\ 0&1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $f(\alpha) = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 1&1 \end{bmatrix}$, we have $\left( e(1/n)^n f(1/n)^{-n} e(1/n)^n\right)^4=\mathrm{Id}$, so there are lots of examples that don't give free groups.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I think your $f(\alpha)$ should have an $\alpha$ in position 2,1

Comment: @WillJagy Is right of course, but I'm past the edit window.

Comment: What about $\alpha=4/3$?

Comment: Your quote doesn't look like referring to an "attempted proof thru the BP equation". It says that for some rationals in $]0,2[$ the BP equation can be used to obtain non-freeness.

Comment: It is a famous open question.

Comment: May I suggest that once you've read the references you have found that you return to summarize them as an answer.

Comment: @Dr. Myerson, yes I will do so.

Comment: @Dr. Speyer, yes you are correct.  I was trying to find a reference that mentions how that group is not free by Brahmagupta-Pell equations.   I think Lyndon and Ullman's paper provides it.

Comment: @YCor, yes $\alpha=4/3$ works (as do 3/2, 5/3 and 5/4).  It's mentioned in Proposition 6 of Lyndon and Ullman's paper.  I'll do my best to understand it and not write something foolish when I summarize the results.

Comment: @user727041 I couldn't guess whether "*yes it works*" means "*yes it's free*" or "*yes it's not free* :) Fortunately the paper is accessible ([here](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1969-153-1)) and Prop 6, at the very end of the paper, says it's not free for these values (with explicit relations).

Comment: @YCor, I'm sorry about not being clear.